# Why is the first button blue in color when I run the PyQt5 program?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I was creating a simple layout with three buttons, but the first button that I create is always Blue in color on my Mac (running Mojave)

```
class Window(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title = "Button Groups PyQt5"
        self.top = 100
        self.left = 100
        self.width = 500
        self.height = 100

        self.initWindow()

    def initWindow(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()

        self.buttonGroup = QButtonGroup()


       # This button always appears to be blue
        button = QPushButton("Python")
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(button, 1)
        hbox.addWidget(button)

        button1 = QPushButton("Java")
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(button1, 2)
        hbox.addWidget(button1)

        button2 = QPushButton("C++")
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(button2, 3)
        hbox.addWidget(button2)

        self.setLayout(hbox)

        self.show()
```

I would like all buttons to be the same color, but the first one is always blue in color like this: https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/6/6/6949e107362afe4376f6386052c9a5b5-full.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button is blue because since it is the first item, it is receiving focus.  If you don't want any of the buttons to receive focus, you can add the following code:

```
button.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
button1.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
button2.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
```

Comment: This is not correct, as the button has that color due to the `autoDefault` property, and changing the focus policy is not an acceptable solution, as it prevents a functionality for the wrong reason.