# Why does my PySide6 wizard page have the first button in blue?

Tags: python, pyside6

Note to reviewers:  I concede this may be a dupe, however IMHO it was marked as a dupe of the wrong question.  Better would be
[Why is the first button blue in color when I run the PyQt5 program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56478207) as mentioned by @musicamente.

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QWizard, QWizardPage

class ThreeButtonsPage(QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        button1 = QPushButton('Button 1', self)
        button2 = QPushButton('Button 2', self)
        button3 = QPushButton('Button 3', self)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(button1)
        hbox.addWidget(button2)
        hbox.addWidget(button3)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

class MyWizard(QWizard):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        first_page = ThreeButtonsPage()
        self.addPage(first_page)
        self.setWindowTitle('Wizard Example')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    wizard = MyWizard()
    wizard.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Why is the first button blue?   I hope the code is pretty self-explanatory.  The first and only the first button appears in blue.  This is not a styling issue as I have dumped the styles of all the buttons just to check.  I have also created the same layout in a single widget app and there is no problem there.  So this seems specific to the wizard.

[image: dialog screen]

Comment: What happens if you press Tab?

Comment: That's how a *default* button is shown on macOs, meaning that pressing <Enter> on your keyboard will trigger it. See the [`autoDefault`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpushbutton.html#autoDefault-prop) property, which is automatically set for QDialog windows (which is the case of QWizard). There already is a related post ([Why is the first button blue in color when I run the PyQt5 program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56478207)), unfortunately the accepted answer is completely inaccurate in its explanation and suggested solution.

Comment: Pressing Tab does nothing.

Comment: The magic autoDefault thing fixes it, thanks so much musicamente that was really annoying me, especially as it only happens in some types of dialog.  It made no sense. I mean I am aware of focus, but by default I can't change the focus anyway in the above code.  Had Tab moved to the next button I would have understood better.  If you add this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Keeely Tab doesn't work because by default macOS only allows switching focus only between text boxes and item views, unless the user has specifically enabled the function for all widgets as a system wide configuration. If you didn't see that behavior previously it probably was because you were not using QPushButtons, or due to the way the buttons were added (possibly through various parent widget levels).